# How to echo a variable that will still be looped outside of the for loop

Tags: php, loops

in PHP

```
    for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++){

       $link = '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?rate='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';

     }
```

?>

in HTML

```
<div class="goLeft">
     <?php echo $link; ?>
</div>
```

When I echo the $link outside of the for loop, only 1 link is displaying. But when I echo the $link inside of the loop. All links is displaying.

Comment: You overwrite $link on each iteration. Concatenate that string instead. `$link =`

Answer (score 1):

> Now you can get the variable outside the forloop

```
  $link =array();

 for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++){
   $link[] = '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?rate='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';

 }

print "<pre>";
print_r ($link);
print "</pre>"; exit;
```

Comment: After getting `$link[]` he will need  another loop to print this

Comment: Then what is the use of for loop, whether he can directly pass the variable. If i have any mistake, correct me, Because me to get a chance to learn from this incident

Comment: I also given my anwser

Answer (score 1):

Link was getting overwritten for every iteration in your loop. You need to concat your links instead of overwritting them.  You can do it as in the following snippet. Declare $link as an empty string and use .= to append your links to it. Then all your links will be displayed when you call `echo $link`

```
$link = "";
for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++){

       $link .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?rate='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply put html inside loop

```
for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++){
   $link = '<div class="goLeft">';
   $link .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?rate='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
   $link .= '</div>';
   echo $link;
 }
```

Or if just need anchor in loop

```
<div class="goLeft">
for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++){
   echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?rate='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
 }
 </div>'
```